# Use of unresolved identifier 'json' (Swift 3) (Alamofire)

Tags: json, swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

I am receiving the error: Use of unresolved identifier 'json'

from this line:  `if let data = json["data"] ...`

This is the snippet of the code relevant to the error

```
        // check response & if url request is good then display the results
        if let json = response.result.value! as? [String: Any] {

            print("json: \(json)")
        }

        if let data = json["data"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            if let weather = data["weather"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                if let uv = weather[0]["uvIndex"] as? String {
                    if let uvI = Int(uv) {
                        self.uvIndex = uvI
                        print ("UV INDEX = \(uvI)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a scoping issue. The `json` variable is only accessible within the `if let` statement.

To solve this, an easy solution is to move the rest of the code inside the braces of the first `if let` statement:

```
if let json = response.result.value! as? [String: Any] {
    print("json: \(json)")
    if let data = json["data"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        if let weather = data["weather"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
            if let uv = weather[0]["uvIndex"] as? String {
                if let uvI = Int(uv) {
                    self.uvIndex = uvI
                    print ("UV INDEX = \(uvI)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from your code, the nesting is starting to make it difficult to read your code. One way to avoid nesting is to use the `guard` statement, which keeps the new variable in the outer scope.

```
guard let json = response.result.value else { return }

// can use the `json` variable here
if let data = json["data"] // etc.
```

Comment: Thank you, fixing the scoping issue, solved the problem!

Comment: Great! If you mark my answer as accepted, it will make it easier to find for others in the future if they have the same problem.